# Enabling libdrizzle support for Gearman on OSX

Tags: php, macos, gearman, libdrizzle

Does anyone know how to get libdrizzle support working for gearman on OSX?

I installed gearmand through ports using the command:

```
sudo port install gearmand +drizzle
```

However when I try to use the libdrizzle flags gearmand throws an error:

```
$ gearmand -q libdrizzle --libdrizzle-mysql
gearmand: unrecognised option '--libdrizzle-mysql'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the MySQL driver backend. Which is kind of sad.

Cheers,
   -Brian

Comment: I ended up just running CentOS in a vm to get it to compile with support only to have drizzle be incredibly unstable. Opted for sqlite instead. Btw, Gearman is pretty sweet, thanks for all the dev time you've put in!